# How to add 3rd storyboard into info.plist

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5, uistoryboard, info.plist

I have an app with 3 storyboards for iPhone, iPhone 5 and iPad. 2 storyboard for iPhone? I just want to go this way due to some obvious reasons.
Everything was working fine, I was manually loaded storyboards respective to screen size in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
Then I duplicated my target and renamed it for another product. Now, whenever I try to run app on a 3.5 inch device it simply does not load the respective storyboard saying this

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'iPhone.storyboard' in bundle NSBundle  (loaded)'"
I triple checked the storyboard name, Copy Bundle Resources and its target membership, All are correct.
The app is loading Storyboard for iPhone 5 and iPad in good way.
Deployment info and info. The list can only have 2 storyboard entries 1) for iPhone and other for iPad. How can add 3rd storyboard into plist.

I am new to Objective-C, So please be kind!

Exact error message it is
2013-07-15 11:20:34.423 AppName[1907:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'iPhone4.storyboard' in bundle NSBundle  (loaded)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x27a5012 0x25cae7e 0x1955f96 0x2f9f 0x2a29 0x150c157 0x150c747 0x150d94b 0x151ecb5 0x151fbeb 0x1511698 0x3202df9 0x3202ad0 0x271abf5 0x271a962 0x274bbb6 0x274af44 0x274ae1b 0x150d17a 0x150effc 0x277d 0x26a5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Here i am loading the storyboards.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480)
    {

        UIStoryboard *iPhone4Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone4.storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        UIViewController *initialViewController = [iPhone4Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }

    else if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568)
    {
        UIStoryboard *iPhone5Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone5.storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        UIViewController *initialViewController = [iPhone5Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }

    else if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 1024)
    {
        UIStoryboard *iPadStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad.storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        UIViewController *initialViewController = [iPadStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Are you using `storyboardWithName:bundle:`?

Comment: @Jumhyn Yes you are right, I am using  UIStoryboard *iPhone4Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone4.storyboard" bundle:nil];

Answer (score 0):

You need to be accessing the main bundle instead of no bundle. The instantiation of your storyboard should look like this:

```
UIStoryboard *iPhone4Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone4.storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Comment: In your error message, it says it is looking for `iPhone.storyboard`, but your code lists it as `iPhone4.storyboard`. Which is correct.

Comment: It's actually named as iPhone4.storyboard. I mistakenly spelled it wrong when posting here.

Comment: Could you copy/pase the exact error message into your question body?

Comment: Target membership is OK. Check the Exact error message now please

Comment: Where are you calling this? Could you post that method as well?

Comment: What happens if you try to switch the storyboards so that the iPhone4 storyboard gets loaded from the plist. Also, just FYI, storyboards can be set up to automatically handle the change in size from iPhone 4 to iPhone 5.

Comment: After plist change it does load, automatic handling is not presenting them right on my side.

Comment: Please help! I need to fix it ASAP.